# Sending SQL DataRow instead of an object

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, class, security

Normally, I create a class object library and then populate it's properties across solutions, e.g. from a website to a wcf web services, referencing class dll in both solutions.

But I just realized someone using a DataRow with same columns as object's properties and sending it across methods as parameter.

May I know which approach is better and if there is any thing wrong with sending DataRow as parameter between solutions or web services.

Answer (score 0):

I really discourage you from doing this. First (and most importantly) because DataRow doesn't support serialization natively, and second because the DataRow is a .NET structure intended to be use together with DataTable.

If, for any reason, you need to use this web service from any "not-dot-net" application, it would be very painful to build an structure like DataRow on the client-side (imagine yourself having to decode the web service response through Javascript, for example). For Web Services, the best approach is to send custom (and very simple) structures.